# Как очистить массив или структуру данных через template?

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

Можно ли вместо `ZeroMemory(x,sizeof(x))` использовать `Zero(x)`?

Пробую набросать...

```
  struct TItem { int x,y,z; } ;
  TItem array[32];
  zero(array);
  //  отдельно обьявляю ф-цию zero
  template <typename T> void TMem::zero(T x[])
  {
     char * z = (char*)&x;
     int i = sizeof(x); // пробовал sizeof(T)
     while (i>0) z[--i] = 0;
  }
```

Пробовал class вместо typename...
Пока не получается вычислить размер аргумента.  Возможно ли в с++ очистить массив используя template? Через #define, конечно, прописать можно, но тогда диспечер не отображает функцию, хочу именно через template. Желательно что б старые версии плюсов ели.

UPD: По совету **free_ze** изменил `template<typename T> void ZeroMemory(T& x)` добавил `&` и массивы и структуры и массивы структур очищаются.

Comment: [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: `template<typename T> void ZeroMemory(T& x)`, но для указателей на буферы это работать не будет.

Comment: @free_ze мне ваш альтернативный вариант тоже нравится, опубликуйте его как ответ (я подожду потом сам опубликую если ответа не будет)

Comment: Это плохой вариант, который ответом не является. Просто интересное свойство вывода типов в шаблонах, тот самый момент, когда `int* a` заметно отличается от `int a[]`. Явно (ответ Harry) или неявно (std::array) нужно предусматривать передачу размера массива.

Comment: @free_ze надо было создать вопрос "очистить массив или структуру". Структуры содежащие union не хотят "обнуляться" по-умолчанию (стековые переменные), а через этот трюк - всё хорошо. Именно такой вариант я себе взял в работу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так...

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void ZeroMem(T (&arr)[N])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        arr[i] = T{};
}
```

Comment: Да, так работает, ещё это может понадобится и если нужно универсально обойти массив.

Comment: @nick_n_a А как, по-вашему, работает `for(auto i: array)`? :)

Comment: это мне ещё похоже предстоит изучить. И перейти с borland на что-то поновее)