# Заполнение матрицы

Tags: c++, null, матрицы

У нас есть матрица а*b. Нужно заполнить её нулями с помощью встроеной функции. Как?

Comment: Как обычно циклом.

Comment: Записать 0 в каждую ячейку. (Каков вопрос, таков и ответ)

Comment: Язык то какой? .

Comment: Сишка, С++.....

Comment: Ну встроенных скорее всего нет.

Comment: либо есть но они еще болше ухудшают оптимизацию

Comment: Хотя нет, я знаю одну хитрость.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745633/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-template один из удобных способов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью пустых фигурных скобок можно заполнить матрицу (или же массив массивов) нулями

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int m[3][4] = {};
    //вывод
    for(auto& row: m) {
       for(auto& val: row) std::cout << val << ' ';
       std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Вот пример http://cpp.sh/9yjju

Comment: Спасибо большое!