# Почему нельзя объявить constexpr D3DXVECTOR3?

Tags: c++, directx, struct, constexpr

Почему вот так: `constexpr RECT DefaultRS = { 0,0,180,52 };` Можно,
а вот так `constexpr D3DXVECTOR3 DefaultCenter = { 0,0,0 };` нельзя?

Добавил текст ошибки:
error C2127: "DefaultCenter": недопустимая инициализация сущности "constexpr" с помощью неконстантного выражения

Comment: Может быть приведёте текст ошибки?

Comment: error C2127: "DefaultCenter": недопустимая инициализация сущности "constexpr" с помощью неконстантного выражения

Comment: А вы чем компилируете С++11, С++14, C++17?

Comment: c++17, вроде-бы...

Comment: Судя по всему вам надо использовать D3DVECTOR, т.к. это простой тип, а D3DXVECTOR3 в вашем случаее скорее всего сложный тип с конструкторами т.д..

Comment: Попробуйте так... `D3DXVECTOR3 DefaultCenter = { 0,};` если конструкторов нету - поможет. А... ещё юнионы мешают инициализировать. Воспользуйтесь fillchar или ZeroMemory. Я делал так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745633/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса `D3DXVECTOR3` все конструкторы являются не `constexpr`. Собственно они являются частью устаревшего API DirectX9X, которое появилось еще до появления в языке `constexpr`.