# Узнать конец динамического массива

Tags: c++

Как можно узнать размер динамического массива, например int* или как получить указатель на его конец.

P.S. массив передается в функцию типа foo(int *).

Comment: Это невозможно.

Comment: Есть косвенные методы, например вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745633/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программист сам должен позаботиться о размере выделенной памяти. Если приложение не критично к скорости выполнения, обычно создают по быстрому свой класс указателя с этими данными. Можно писать как вам удобно, например так:

```
// g++ -Wall -Wpedantic pointertoarray.cpp
# include <iostream>
template<class T>
class PointerToArray{
public :
  PointerToArray(T*t,size_t n = 1):p(t),s(n){}
  PointerToArray(PointerToArray const & x):p(x.p),s(x.s){}
  T & operator  *()const{return  * p;}
  T * operator  ->()const{return  p;}
  T & operator [](size_t i)const{return *(p + i) ; }
  T * operator +(size_t i)const{return p + i ; }
  T * begin()const{return p ;}
  T * end()const{return p + s ;}
  size_t size()const{return s;}
private :
  T * p ;
  size_t s ;
};

void g(PointerToArray<int> px) {
  std::cout << "size of array is "<<px.size()<<std::endl;
  std::cout << "px[5]=="<<px[5]<<std::endl;
  std::cout << "*(px+5)=="<<(*(px+5))<<std::endl; }

int main() {
  int * xp = new int[10];
  xp[5]=777;
  PointerToArray<int> px(xp,10);
  g(px);
  delete[]xp; }
```

результат:

```
> ./a.out 
size of array is 10
px[5]==777
*(px+5)==777
```

Comment: Зачем такие мучения при наличии array и vector?

Comment: @Harry имя класса говорит, что это **не**  массив, а ссылка. Так-как ссылки на массив в Си нет, только указатель, то и предлагается такой комфорт.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а причем тут Си, если и в вопросе и в вашем ответе C++?

Comment: @Герман Борисов Если есть код большой / древний, который нет возможности / желания модифицировать на использование плюсовых библиотек. То данный выход передаёт ссылку на массив в современный код.

Comment: Но для использования этого класса все равно все придется модифицировать.

Answer (score 8):

В общем случае - никак.

В некоторых версиях определенных компиляторов можно получить эту информацию, но способ не универсален и может перестать работать в любой момент.

В данном случае либо функция foo должна принимать в качестве дополнительного параметра количество элементов в массиве, либо должен быть договор, что массив оканчивается определенным значением. Например, у всех функций, принимающих строки есть соглашение, что массив заканчивается символом с кодом 0

PS. В C++ лучше вообще отказаться от динамических массивов и использовать стандартные контейнеры array или vector. При необходимости стыковки с внешним кодом, они легко преобразуются в указатель на массив.