# Как создать массив в функции, используя ее параметр

Tags: c, массивы, компилятор

```
#include <stdio.h>

void CountingSort(int arr[], int n, int k) {
    int aux[n];
    int freq[k];
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0, 5, 1, 2, 8, 11, 0, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int k = 12;

    ...

}
```

Столкнулся с такой проблемой — необходимо передать массив в функцию и в ней создать новый массив, такой же размерности, как исходный. Но возникает ошибка: «*expression must have a constant value*». Отсюда вопрос, как это исправить, и почему такая передача `n` не работает? (Делал по гайду, там был точно такой же способ, но все работало, видимо компилятор VS не допускает этого).

Comment: потому что VLA - нестандартная вещь и может не поддерживаться

Comment: Для таких случаев я вам рекомендую template http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745633/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-template

Comment: @pavel, в Си VLA — это давно **стандартная вещь**, но, действительно, может не поддерживаться...

Comment: @nick_n_a, речь идет о Си без плюсов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно немного переделать, примерно вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void CountingSort(int* arr, int n, int k) {
  int* aux = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  int* freq = malloc(sizeof(int)*k);
  // ... блабла
  free(freq);
  free(aux);
}

int main(void) {
  int arr[] = {0,5,1,2,8,11,0,3};
  int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  int k = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  CountingSort(arr,n,k);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 2):

Массивы с размером, неизвестным во время компиляции, — это так называемые *массивы переменного размера* (англ. VLA, Variable Length Arrays). Они были введены в язык стандартом C99, однако начиная со стандарта C11 реализации не обязаны поддерживать VLA.

Скорее всего ваш компилятор просто не поддерживает VLA, тогда вам стоит динамически выделить память в куче для ваших массивов:

```
int *aux = malloc(n * sizeof *aux);
int *freq = malloc(n * sizeof *freq);
```

Можете также воспользоваться макросом `_STDC_NO_VLA_`, который позволяет узнать, поддерживает ли реализация VLA:

```
#if _STDC_NO_VLA_ == 1
    int *aux = malloc(n * sizeof *aux);
    int *freq = malloc(n * sizeof *freq);
#else
    int aux[n];
    int freq[n];
#endif
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так и думал, что надо будет выделять память.