# "Переменные" в шаблонах с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Всем здравствуйте. Недавно заинтересовался как же работает std::end и когда пошёл смотреть реализацию, увидел там приблизительно вот такой код(просто сейчас не могу посмотреть):

```
template<typename T, size_t sz> constexpr end( T (&arr)[sz])
{
   return arr+sz;
}
```

Насколько я понял `sz` отвечает за размер массива, но почему то оно определенно не обычной переменной, а как-то в шаблоне. Что это за магическая "переменная" которую определяют в шаблоне и для чего она нужна?

Comment: Вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745636/17974

Comment: В шаблонах не переменные. В шаблонах константы. typename - это тип. Не какойнибудь - а конкретный. size_t - требует для sz число. sz внутри будет константой равной колличеству элементов в массиве. arr+sz даст "указатель" на следующий за последним элементом внутри массива arr.  Нужно это, что бы определить в цикле/итераторе что этот элемент уже нельзя брать в расчёт, что последовательность закончилась.

Comment: Шаблонным параметром может быть не только _тип_, но и _значение_. Называется это [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). Т.е. при создании экземпляра шаблона вместо `T` будет подставлен некоторый тип, а вместо `sz` будет подставлено некоторое значение. `но почему то оно определенно не обычной переменной, а как-то в шаблоне` Обычной переменной? Примерно так: `end( T (&arr)[sz], size_t sz)`? Значение `sz` — это часть _типа массива_. Данная величина должна быть известна на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @wololo, спасибо, если грубо, то работу 'non-type-template-parameter`, можно сравнить с макросами и никаких переменных при этом не создается?

Comment: @n1kzzz, это не макрос.  Начиная с С++ 20 для таких параметров отводится неизменяемая статическая память. Разумеется, компилятор может оптимизировать и не аллоцировать память.

Comment: Да, это в какой-то степени _похоже_ на макросы. Можно сказать, что в теле шаблона вместо параметра просто подставляется конкретное значение. Т.е. то, что обозначается non-type параметром не является _объектом_. Например, вы не можете взять адрес такого параметра. НО есть некоторые тонкости. 1) non-type параметр может быть ссылкой (т.е. адрес берётся (того объекта, на который ссылается ссылка)), 2) Начиная с C++20 non-type параметр может иметь _классовый тип_. Такой параметр таки обозначает некоторый объект со статическим классом памяти.

Comment: @PakUula, `Начиная с С++ 20 для таких параметров отводится неизменяемая статическая память` Только если параметр имеет классовый тип (и то не любой, а с кучей ограничений). Для обычных параметров вида `size_t sz` никакая память не отводится. Такой параметр есть prvalue. Для сравнения, литералы вида `42`, `true` и т.п. также являются prvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не переменная, а параметр шаблона. Когда компилятор встречает в коде `std::end(some_array)`, он ищет подходящую сигнатуру.

Если `some_array` имеет тип `SomeType[n]` - массив типа `SomeType` с `n` элементами, то компилятор инстанциирует шаблон `template< class T, std::size_t N > constexpr T* end( T (&array)[N] ) noexcept;`, связав тип `SomeType` с параметром `T`, а число элементов `n` свяжет с параметром `sz`.

Этот шаблон работает только для массивов фиксированного размера:

1. для переменной, объявленной как `int somevar[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10}`,
2. а также для переменной с типом `массив фиксированного размера`:

```
typedef int IntArray16[16];
IntArray16 arr;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы уточнить, чем параметр шаблона отличается от обычной константы?

Comment: и в чём разница между `template <size_t sz>` и `template < const size_t sz> если ни то, ни то мы не можем изменять

Comment: T<1> и T<2> это разные типы и для них генерится разный код

Comment: @n1kzzz, про `const size_t sz` - в стандарте не смотрел, нашел на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters): *optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers are ignored*, то есть модификатор `const` в non-type параметре игнорируется. Почему? Потому, что не-типовой параметр связывается на этапе компиляции, то есть аргумент должен быть константой.

Comment: @n1kzzz non-type параметр - это константа с областью видимости, равной телу инстанциированного шаблона. [An identifier that names a non-type template parameter of class type T denotes a static storage duration object of type const T](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). Однако компилятор имеет полное право оптимизировать код и не аллоцировать память под параметр.